Sentinel-2 image too dark
I downloaded an image through SentinelHub API, with the following specifications:

.tiff file format
RGB channels
16m/pixel (resampled)
Sentinel-2 L2A

The result is the following:

Screenshot from SNAP 


Screenshot from QGIS 

The image looks very dark, why is that?

Similar question from yesterday, perhaps the answer helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/488297/238384

Your image has no contrast enhancement / stretch applied.
Change contrast enhancement to Stretch to Min/Max and try different Min/Max value settings.


